# How do I change the language in Spring STS Dashboard

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ide

I downloaded the mac version here https://spring.io/tools/sts/all 
The language in the Dashboard seems a bit off. Has anyone experienced this issue?
[Screenshot of STS with Dashboard open.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDOfJ.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

This is happening due to a Font rendering issue while using JavaFx. There is already an issue open to track this -  https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4422. 
A simple workaround is to switch to older dashboard until the issue is fixed. You can switch to old by going to Preferences-->Spring-->Dashboard and then checking the "Use Old Dashboard" checkbox.